# Running an over/under-clocking app without rooting

Tags: clock-speed

Can it be done?  I'd like to be able to set clock limits based on a number of conditions, such as battery temperature, charging/not charging, and what radios are turned on.  I'm aware that there are apps for rooted phones that will allow me to do this, but I'm wondering if there are any that don't need my phone to be rooted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but this simply isn't possible.  You have to have administrator access to your phone to control the processor's speed.

Comment: Shucks.  Looks like I may be rooting my phone in the not too distant future.